# How parse nested object/array using jsoncpp parser in C++?

Tags: c++, json, parsing

For example:

```
    Json::Reader reader;
    Json::Value val;
    ifstream file("JSON/test.json");
    bool success = reader.parse(file, val, false);
    vector<string> obj = val.getMemberNames();

    for (int i = 0; i < val.size(); i++)
    {
        // switch type of value
        switch (val.get(obj.at(i), "default").type())
        {
            case stringValue:
                cout << "I'm string" << endl;
                ... need to save **membername** and **value**
                break;
            case intValue:
                cout << "I'm int"  << endl;
                ... need to save **membername** and **value**
                break;
            case nullValue:
                cout << "I'm null"  << endl;
                break;
            case arrayValue:
                 ... code to parse an array (with nested sure) ...
                 ... need to save
                break;
            case objectValue:
                ... code to parse an object (with nested sure) ...
                ... need to save 
                break;
        }
    }
```

Example **JSON file** (JSON/test.json):

```
{
    "layout": "fit",
    "xtype": "viewport",
    "height": 200,
    "style": {
                "backgroundColor": "46f0a8"
             },

           "items": 
           [
             {
                "title": "Management Console",
                "padding": "10 10 10 10",
                "bodyPadding": 10,
                "autoScroll": true,
                "items2": [1, 2, 3]
             }
           ]
 }
```

In array **items**, we can see another array (nested) called **items2**.

May experience the following for arrays:

```
array[Jacob, Joseph] or
array[{name: Jacob, name: Joseph}] or
array[{name: Jacob}, {name: Joseph}]
```

For objects it's similar. In each field, can of course be **many nested objects/arrays**. How do I save data in C++ variables?

Comment: It is quite unclear to me, what are you really asking for. I see 3 questions. How do I process `array` data and `object` data in `jsoncpp` library? How do I adapt to different data storing conventions? How do I handle general/nested cases?

Comment: It is unclear whether you want to parse into a predefined C++ class, or you want to parse arbitrary JSON data. For the latter case, there is really no point converting `JSON::Value` into other formats; just use `JSON::Value` directly.

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to make your main parsing function recursive. Then use STL classes like vector that allow you to dynamically allocate more storage for your data.